# What does negative one mean when passed as a date in the DATEDIFF function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand the following T-SQL code:

```
    select DATEADD(
                MONTH, 
                DATEDIFF(
                    MONTH, 
                    -1, 
                    GETDATE()) -1,
                -1)
```

What does `-1` indicate when passing into DATEDIFF? According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), it should be a date parameter.

Comment: Which `-1` are you asking about here, there are 3.

Comment: The -1 passed into `DATEDIFF`. It's the second argument of `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: Though, you could answer this yourself simply with `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, -1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the `-1` for the 2nd parameter for `DATEDIFF`, and the 3rd parameter for `DATEADD` will be implicitly converted to a `datetime`. You can find what the value would be with a simple expression:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, -1);
```

Which gives 1899-12-31 00:00:00.000. For the "old" date and time data types (`(small)datetime`), they allow conversion from numerical data type (such as an `int` or `decimal`). `0` represents 1900-01-01 00:00:00 and each full integer value represents a day. So `-1` is 1899-12-31 00:00:00.000, `2` would be 1900-01-03 00:00:00.000 and `5.5` would be 1900-01-06 12:00:00.000 (as
`.5` represents 12 hours).

For the *new* date and time data types, this conversion does not exist.

In truth, the above could likely be much more easily written as the following though:

```sql
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1);
```

Here the `-1` means the end of the month 1 month prior to the date of the first parameter (in this case the current date). The second parameter for `EOMONTH` is optional, so `EOMONTH(GETDATE())` would return the last day of the current month, and `EOMONTH(GETDATE(),2)` would return the last day of the month in 2 months time (2023-03-31 at time of writing).